# PHP and PHPSec trying to make a connection and getting errors

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I'm trying to find the easiest way to test a sFTP connection in PHP. I don't intend to upload/download any files. I just want to open a connection, confirm it is OK, then close it.

I came across 'phpSec' which seems to do what I want, except, I can't make it work.

My script so far is:

```
<?php
require_once '../lib/phpSec/bootstrap.php';
require_once 'SplClassLoader.php';
$classLoader = new SplClassLoader('phpSec', '../Generic/lib');
$classLoader->register();


$server = "123.456.789.012";
$port = "22";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx"; 

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'c:\Apache\htdocs\phpseclib');
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);

include 'phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php';

define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);

$sftp = new Net_SFTP($server);

// Check SFTP Connection
if (!$sftp->login($username, $password)) 
    {
        echo 'Login Failed.';

        print "</br>";

        $ERR1 = $sftp->getSFTPErrors();
        print_r($ERR1);

        print "</br>";

        $ERR2 = $sftp->getErrors();
        print_r($ERR2);
    }
else
    {
        echo 'Connected to SFTP.';

        echo $sftp->pwd();
    }

?>
```

The output from this is 'Login Failed'.
The output of `$sftp->getSFTPErrors();` is a blank Array.
The output of `$sftp->getErrors();` is a blank Array.

On the sFTP server I can see the connection in the log files, with the error:

> 2014-03-24 11:36:35 [000001ew] {450} SSH_ERROR_CODE: 11 -> Wrong
>   packet size

Is there anything else I can change? What packet size should I use? Does it actually matter if I'm not transferring any fles?

Comment: Change `define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX)` to `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX)` and then call `$sftp->getLog()` and post the output. Well, copy / paste it into pastebin.com and post the link to that.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why your statements are not working, but in order to see the errors of the objects method you should use try and catch.

```
try{
    $sftp->login($username, $password);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Hopefully this assists in the debugging process!

Comment: Thanks, but that just returns a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use PHP unbuilt functions?
They are more reliable than 3rd party software.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortnately I get: Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

Comment: Means, you don't have PHP compiled with ssh2 support,.. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php

Comment: thanks for the link, but I was hoping to avoid the whole download / compile / load etc process. I'm running on Windows for test, but Linux for live so it means having to go through the process twice, and it's not really my area of expertise.

Comment: @IGGt Ok understand that. If all fails, chances are high that on your linux live server, the ssh2 functions are already compiled in. Maybe testing locally on a virtual box linux image is even better than windows. Just an idea! Good luck anyways with your project

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the ideas. I think the problem ultimately was with the sFTP server. As I deleted the user, then re-created it again, and now I am getting a succesful connection.